How do I get C typedefs of opaque structs into a dictionary?
I'm trying to use cppyy to wrap a C library. The header file contains opaque structs and typedefs of pointers to them. If I just do the normal JIT, everything works. If I try to use rootcling or genreflex with cppyy.load_reflection_info(), the typedefs of opaque types are missing and the code breaks.
Given the following sample header:
struct _test_type;
typedef struct _test_type * test_type;

struct _other_type {
    int foo;
};
typedef struct _other_type * other_type;

void test_func(test_type foo, other_type bar)

I can't get test_type to get into a dictionary.
